# i'm confused by javascript execution order

Tags: javascript

Can you explain me the difference between these code blocks?

I can't get it!

---

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
        var str;

        var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('get','http://localhost:8080/new/text.jsp',true);
        request.onload=function(){
            str=request.responseText;

        };
        request.send();
        $('h1').text(str);
    });
```

---

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    var str;

    var request= new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('get','http://localhost:8080/new/text.jsp',true);
    request.onload=function(){
        str=request.responseText;   
        $('h1').text(str);
    };
    request.send();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This because an Ajax request (XMLHttpRequest) executes async. The onload function is triggered when you get a response. In the response you do need to check for status code and response code.

The first piece of code. Does not wait for the response but just puts `str` in to the `h1`. The second piece of code wait for the request to process and when you get a response it will use that code into the `h1`.